# Firestore document get during initstate or during the build as future builder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I was wondering what is the better option to get documents from firestore.
Should i run the getdocuments in initstate or should I run it as a future builder.

So far these are the pros and cons i have seen.
initstate - if I were to retrieve it initState, then everytime i click on a post to see its details, and when i go back, the initstate runs again, creating more documents read. However, this does help refresh certain values, incase of a user bookmarking a post, that way the bookmark value gets updated, however in the cost of more documents read.

futurebuilder - seems cost efficient in the sense that, when i click on a post and go back, no more documents are retrieved from firestore, however, if i were to bookmark the post in the postdetails page, the value does not get updated. However to work this around, i could just remove the bookmark value in the Post page.

I have however, used the getdocuments in the initstate when i go into the postdetails page by deseralizing it.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling getDocuments() is deprecated for get() as per the [change log](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore/changelog).

I would do one of the following:

- If using initState, the easiest way to deal with this is to store a
  Future variable in your state. In initState make the API call and
  store the Future. You can then pass this Future to FutureBuilder.
- Keep using FutureBuilder, then when you edit the data make an async
  operation to update the database and after the database is updated
  call setState to reflect the changes on the UI.
- Use a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), which is similar to FutureBuilder, but instead
  of building only once, it rebuilds each time there's a change on the
  stream it's attached to. This way you just need to update the
  datasource and the widget will update itself with the new data.

So my answer would be it depends on your use case. If your data updates every min/sec while you use the app, it needs updates asynchronously at a certain interval, in that case StreamBuilder is the best option but If your use case is to just get the data, and display it, then you can use FutureBuilder.